# Azure Service Bus Subscription

Tags: azure, events, azureservicebus

i want to develop a Game using Azure Cloud but i am not sure which ressources i could use for it. Folowing is my problem:

1. There is one publisher which is providing some messages. I need to find a way to add subscriber on demand. That means whenever i need more subscriber i need to add them without changing any settings on the portal.
2. All subscriber needs to get the published message at the same time.
3. Received message from the publisher needs to be deleted for all subscriber at the same time.

Is there a ressource or a way which fits theese needs?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Azure SignalR Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-overview) is WebSocket Gateway service that covers all your requirements.

While you could always host your own server, the service supports [scaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-scale-aspnet-core) out.